# Why is my echo'd PHP variable still producing nothing?

Tags: php, variables, xpath, extract, href

I recently was provided an excellent answer on how to handle extracting my URL from HTML content here:

[Extracting context from a set point in the middle of an HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173541/extracting-context-from-a-set-point-in-the-middle-of-an-html-file)

But after implementing the code, I still show nothing from the echo call on the variable afterwards.  I know if I echo get_the_content(), it shows the entire post body as it should, but maybe its not being handled properly by loadHTML()?  I implemented the code as provided (which to my knowledge works perfectly aka no errors) and within the foreach loop assigned the extracted URL to a variable so I could use it in the location necessary, as shown by the code below:

```
<?php
    $doc   = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $a = 1;
    if (have_posts()) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<div class="ORtrack">
    <?php
        $success = $doc->loadHTML(get_the_content());
        if ($success === FALSE) {
            // error handling
        } else {
            $hrefs = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'mp3')]/@href");
            foreach ($hrefs as $href) {
                $BEmp3s = $href;
            }
        };
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCP<?php echo $a; ?> = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_<?php echo $a; ?>",
    {
        mp3: "<?php echo $BEmp3s; ?>"
    }, {
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_<?php echo $a; ?>",
        volume: 0.5
    });
</script>
    ....
<?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>
```

There is only ONE MP3 URL to grab per Post body and I always want the first one if for some reason there does end up being multiple MP3 URL's, so is it really necessary to build the array?  What am I still missing and is this the most efficient manner to accomplish this?

Comment: You do not initialize the `$BEmp3s` variable.

Comment: Have you tried with `var_dump` instead of `echo` in order to see the content of the variable??

Comment: try var_dump, that puts stuff out ever if its null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one MP3 being returned by your xpath, then don't use a foreach loop. That's overkill. A single item can be retrieved by doing

```
$BEmp3s = $hrefs->item(0)
```

and you can check if the xpath actually found anything via

```
if ($hrefs->length > 0) { ... found something ... }
```

Comment: Since I only use the MP3 URL once as well, wouldn't it be best to just reference $hrefs->item(0) directly and not even assign it to a variable?

Comment: If you can guarantee that there's always at least one result, then sure.